# Sweetalert as a service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m trying to create a CRUD in Angular. Aparently the CRUD works but i want to improve code so i need avoid some sweetalert  code to use only once. I think I can create a service and create different functions, like this

```
export ModalClass{
    showconfirmdialog(title, text, icon){
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
          icon: "success",
        });
      } else {
        swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
      }
    });
    }
}
```

Then in .ts file *inject* this class and functions like this

```
import {ModalClass} from 'blabla'
    deletefunction(){
         this.http.get('API').subscribe()
         this.ModalClass.showconfirmdialog('Was deleted','all ok', 'fa-ok')
     }
```

Nothing happens. I debug response and return something like

> [Object Object]

So the question is : How can i create a service with reutilizable code and inject this in ts files?

Comment: What angular version?

Comment: Angular 7, last version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create you own service, there are a few packages that do it for you.

The best IMO is the official package: [@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2).

**1 - Install it:**

```
npm install --save sweetalert2 @sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2
```

**2 - Import the module:**

```
import { SweetAlert2Module } from '@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2';

@NgModule({
    //=> Basic usage (forRoot can also take options, see details below)
    imports: [SweetAlert2Module.forRoot()],

    //=> In submodules only:
    imports: [SweetAlert2Module],

    //=> In submodules only, overriding options from your root module:
    imports: [SweetAlert2Module.forChild({ /* options */ })]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**3 - Use it.**

See the documentation [here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2#link-api)

**Additional answer:**

Of course that you can develop your own service, but you will need to wrap all your calls within [NgZone.run()](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) and take care of a lot of problems that will appear to you, create a buggy service that will give you a lot of headaches.

Trust me, I did this with a lot of libraries in the beginning of Angular 2+, when there hasn't packages like this.

Comment: This would a possible option but i don´t have time to rewrite code, old code use sweetalert js directly.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre anyway you will need to change any code inside angular to use your service or a 3rd party service. I recommend the 3rd party one.

Comment: Did you try to show a sweetalert toast with ng-sweetalert? I can test this package in my free time but application apart to modals uses toast.